Bounds on the Kolmogorov distance
Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables with distribution functions $F_X, F_Y, F_Z$.
The Kolmogorov distance is defined as
$$d_K(X, Z) = \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} |F_X(t)-F_Z(t)|.$$
Assume that $Z$ has a bounded p.d.f. $f_Z$ and that $Y$ is a centered r.v. with finite second moment.
I am looking for bounds of the form
$$ d_K(X+Y, Z) \leq d_K(X,Z) + r(Y,Z), $$
where $r(Y,Z)$ depends on $Y$ and $Z$ in some way.
What I have so far
So far, I have the following: For any $\varepsilon>0$ it holds that
$$ d_K(X+Y, Z) \leq d_K(X,Z) + \varepsilon \lVert f_Z\rVert_\infty + P(|Y|>\varepsilon). \qquad(1)$$
(Proof sketch below)
Using the Markov inequality to bound $P(|Y|>\varepsilon) \leq E[Y^2]/\varepsilon^2$ and taking $\varepsilon=E[Y^2]^\frac{1}{3}$ then gives
$$ d_K(X+Y, Z) \leq d_K(X,Z) + (\lVert f_Z\rVert_\infty + 1) E[Y^2]^\frac{1}{3}. $$
When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, there is a better bound (Lemma 3 in this paper):
$$ d_K(X+Y, Z) \leq d_K(X,Z) + \lVert f_Z\rVert_\infty \cdot E|Y|. $$
By Jensen's inequality $E|Y| \leq E[Y^2]^\frac{1}{2}$, so we get the exponent 1/2, which is better than the one of 1/3 above, at least when $E[Y^2]<1$.
Questions

My main question is the following:
Can I do any better than above (exponent 1/3) when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?
Even if you don't have an answer to this exact problem, I appreciate any ideas/references on how to bound $d_K(X+Y, Z)$ for 'small $Y$'.
If you have any (preferably citeable) reference for (1), I would much appreciate it.
I will include a sketch of my proof of (1), please tell me if my reasoning is unsound.

Proof of (1)
For $\varepsilon>0, t\in\mathbb{R}$, it holds that
$$\begin{aligned}
        P(X+Y \leq t)
            &= P(X+Y \leq t, |Y|\leq \varepsilon) + P(X+Y\leq t, |Y|>\varepsilon)\\
            &\leq P(X - \varepsilon \leq t) + P(|Y|>\varepsilon)\\
            &= F_X(t+\varepsilon) + P(|Y| > \varepsilon),
\end{aligned}$$
hence
$$\begin{aligned}
        P(X+Y\leq t) - P(Z\leq t)
            &\leq F_X(t+\varepsilon) - F_Z(t) + P(|Y| > \varepsilon)\\
            &\leq |F_X(t+\varepsilon) - F_Z(t+\varepsilon)| + |F_Z(t+\varepsilon) - F_Z(t)| + P(|Y| > \varepsilon)\\
            &\leq d_K(X, Z) + \varepsilon \lVert f_Z\rVert_\infty + P(|Y| > \varepsilon).
\end{aligned}$$
The lower bound follows similarly.
